# How can I delete table tr data comping from api in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to delete `table tr` user table, data coming from API, please help. I tried following code.

```
$("principleTable").find("tr").hide();
$("#delAgentModal").modal("hide");
```

Comment: Could you add more code/context? Remember we know nothing about the project you're working on... Also, what does the "data coming from API" look like?

Comment: `principleTable` seems to be no valid, selector (this would be an element selector), maybe you're missing a `.` or `#` ?

Comment: Just give the table's HTML, so we can able to know on which event you are deleting the row. Are there any buttons at each row to delete the row? In this case you have delete the HTMl tr and also call the api for deleting the same data from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Use '#' for ID and '.' for class.

$("#principleTable").find("tr").hide();
$("#delAgentModal").modal("hide");